# How should I handle sparse instance variables from a gem class like feedzirra?

Tags: ruby, database, feed

My objective is to use feedzirra, or a viable alternative, to access many varying RSS feeds and store them in ActiveRecords for later processing.  Obviously, these feeds will vary in composition.

Just running the sample feedzirra code, I've found that its implementation of instance variables is sparse.  If the feed doesn't provide the information, the variable is left at nil.  This is okay, but as soon as I run a method like sanitize, I receive a NoMethod error on Nil.

Doing some research, I see there is an instance_variables method that would allow me to grab active variables.  I could use that but it leaves the problem as to later downstream code that may be checking for instance variables that simply don't exist.

I'm torn on how to handle the situation of sparse instance variables.  As I write my code, I need to be able to rely on the input so that I can run processes and methods without (too much) concern as to its reliability or existence.

At this point, I've simply set a rescue NoMethodError trap which is wholly insufficient.  I figure that I have to start with some of my own "sanitize" methods to ensure that the input is both safe and reliable.  But, when I get nil input, what do I do?  I cannot leave it nil as later methods will fail.  I could inject some standard string such as " " or "unavailable", either of which could occur in the wild.

This is the first time that I have gathered input that I'd considered wholly unsafe and unreliable.  I need recommendations on what I need to do to clean it up before I process it.

Comment: Why can't you check whether something is set before trying to use it?

Comment: It isn't that I can't.  But, I am going to do some serious heavy lifting on these feeds.  I would prefer to know they are clean and reliable.  I'm not sure this is necessarily the time to do it, during fetch.  I may need to do it during the next stage, during parse which will either use feedzirra or DataActive, most likely.  But, the question will be the same and the answer will probably be the same as well.  I need to build a safe and reliable data stream from unsafe and unreliable data.  How do I take Nil and make it safe and reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, lacking a viable alternative, I have fallen back to checking for nil on the variables as soon as I receive them and setting them to pre-defined values that I can check later needed.

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but getting nil NoMethodError's isn't either...